# Foreign Key is only working on some models in Spring JPA project

Tags: java, mysql, spring, database, jpa

I ran into a strange problem with my spring jpa project. Basically for one of my models, it seems the foreign key is not working as supposed.
In my project i have a model class "Player" and another "PlayerStats".

In "Player Stats" i add stats for an individual player and store it in my db.
I use basic html for a simple web form for data input.
This works fine but the column "player_id" is always NULL.
It wouldnt bother me but i would like to display the idividual stats for each player in another table and if i cant fix this every other players stats will be available to view.

I have however set it up the same way for different model classes in my project and i have no issue. For example i have a user model class thats "user_id" is used as a foreign key in model class "Team" and "Player. No issue seen there.
So any help on where i am going wrong is greatly appreciated.

## 1. Player Model Class

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="User_Player")
public class Player implements Serializable {

@OneToOne
private User user;
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

private String playerName;
private String dob;
private String hometown;
private String weight;
private String height;
private Position position;



}
```

## 2. PlayerStats model

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="Player_Stats")


public class PlayerStats implements Serializable {

@ManyToOne
private Player player;


private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

private int td;
private int rushYards;
private int recYards;
private int returnYards;
private int throwingYards;
private int throwAttenpts;
private int throwSuccess;
private int receptions;
private int rushTD;
private int recTD;
private int fumbles;
private int fumblesRecovered;
private int forcedFumbles;
private int sacks;
private int puntsBlocked;
private int fgScored;
private int fgMissed;
private int punts;
private int tackle;

public Opponents opponents;
 }
```

## 3. PlayerStats controller

```
@Slf4j
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("PlayerStats")
 public class PlayerStatsController {

 private PlayerStatsRepository playerStatsRepository;

 public PlayerStatsController(PlayerStatsRepository playerStatsRepository) 
{this.playerStatsRepository = playerStatsRepository;}

@Autowired
PlayerStatsRepository service;

@GetMapping("/addPlayerStats/{id}")
public String showSignUpFormPlayer(Player player) {
    return "addPlayerStats";
}

@PostMapping("/addPlayerStats/{id}")
public String processPlayer(@Valid PlayerStats playerStats, BindingResult result, 
 SessionStatus sessionStatus,
                            @AuthenticationPrincipal Player player, Model model) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "playerStats";
    }

    //playerStats.setPl(player);
    service.save(playerStats);
    model.addAttribute("playerStats", service.findAll());
    return "login";
    }
```

## 4. User Model

```
   @Entity
    @Data
    @NoArgsConstructor(access= AccessLevel.PRIVATE, force=true)
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    public class User implements UserDetails {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private final String username;
    private final String password;
    //private final String fullname;


    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return Arrays.asList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
  }
```

Comment: For your bidirectional mapping between `Player` and `PlayerStats` you need to set link between two objects.

So before you save your child object `PlayerStats` just add the link of `Player` to it. `playerStats.setPlayer(player);`

Comment: i had that line in originally and commented it out, i re added it but still no success. Maybe i need to rebuild my table? Also i didnt require that line of code in my other models.

Answer (score 1):

As Sariq said you should setPlayer to playerStats.

```
playerStats.setPlayer(player);
```

Also what I'd recommend doing is explicitly declaring foreign key in PlayerStats class. Do so by using @JoinColumn annotation, and make sure to use exact name as you have it in the database.

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "player_id") // player_id has to match your foreign key in the database
private Player player;
```

Comment: I have added that line but it still does not populate the player_id column in my database. When i debug i can see the id for that player being passed through however but it still doesnt propogate to the db. I have also tried the @JoinColumn approach but that still doesnt work.

Comment: Try adding nullable = false inside @JoinColumn and see how that works / what exceptions you might get.

Comment: Nope, doesnt work either. Heres what i see when i dubug over this (in comments below):

 playerStats.setPlayer(player); // Player = null

Comment: Then that seems to be the problem. Your player entity that you set to PlayerStats is null and therefore the foreign key is also null.

Comment: But beside where it says "Player = null" it also says "id = 11" which is the correct ID for the player i am adding stats to. SO why does it pick up the id and not the actual player? How would i change it?

Comment: do i need to set up a userDetailRepository for my player? Thats the only difference in the models of the user/player and player/playersStats that i can see

Answer (score 0):

So i figured out what the issue was. The @AuthenticationPrincipal annotation was causing the error. I believe that should be used for getting data for a user, using userDetailsService method. When i removed that the code worked as expected. Thanks!